# Hierarchical listing of a folder tree using Windows API

Tags: c++, recursion, winapi

I use this code to list recursively a folder and its subfolders in C++, the code works fine, I modified it from many Stackoverflow questions asking about recursive folder listing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
#define INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES ((DWORD)-1)
#endif  

void findFiles (const std::string & spath)
{

struct HandleWrapper
{
   HANDLE hFind;        
  ~HandleWrapper () {if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ::FindClose (hFind); } 
} wrapper;

size_t i = 1;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

std::string sourcepath = spath + std::string ("\\*.*");
wrapper.hFind = FindFirstFile (sourcepath.c_str (), &FindFileData);


if (wrapper.hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

do
  {

  std::string fullpath =
  std::string (spath) + std::string ("\\") + std::string (FindFileData.cFileName);

  if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && std::string FindFileData.cFileName) != "." && std::string (FindFileData.cFileName) != "..")
  
    findFiles (fullpath);

  else
   
    std::cout << i++ << "-" << FindFileData.cFileName<<std::endl;
  
  } while (FindNextFile (wrapper.hFind, &FindFileData));

}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
std::string spath (argv[1]);
findFiles (spath);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is if you have a tree like this:

```
A file
B another file
C folder
D another folder
E file
F file
```

This program will list `A and B` then it will go into `C` and whatever subfolders it might contains, then will do the same for `D` then it will list files 'E and F' in the parent folder, I really want it to list `A, B, E and F` then go to subfolders `C and D`.
Any idea doing it without resorting to external libraries?

Comment: Just split the do/while loop into two loops. In the first loop, print all files and ignore all folders. In the seconds loop, ignore all files and call the recursive function for each folder.

Comment: Should probably address the correctness issue first. You cannot, ever, implement a general purpose file management library using code page encoding. That said, why reinvent the wheel? C++ already gives you everything you need.

Comment: Why do these functions still exist in the API?

Comment: Because not every program is written in C++. And for those programs written in C++, the file system implementation is eventually going to have to call into the OS. It's not like programming languages live in a vacuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shubham said, you need to use a queue to complete the function you want.

When traversing a folder, if a folder is encountered, push it into the queue, and then pop the folder from the queue after traversing it, thereby achieving a breadth traversal of the folder.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
queue<std::string> qFolders;

void findFiles(string Path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findResult;
    HANDLE handle = NULL;

    if (qFolders.size() > 0)
    {
        std::string tempFolder = qFolders.front();
        tempFolder.append("\\*.*");
        handle = FindFirstFile(tempFolder.c_str(), &findResult);
        cout << qFolders.front() << endl;
        do
        {
            if (findResult.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (lstrcmp(".", findResult.cFileName) == 0 || lstrcmp("..", findResult.cFileName) == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                tempFolder = qFolders.front();
                tempFolder.append("\\").append(findResult.cFileName);
                qFolders.push(tempFolder);
            }
            else {
                cout << "  " << findResult.cFileName << endl;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(handle, &findResult));
        qFolders.pop();
        if(!qFolders.empty())
        {
            findFiles(qFolders.front());
        }
    }
    if (handle)
    {
        FindClose(handle);
        handle = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    qFolders.push("D:\\test\\t");
    findFiles(qFolders.front());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You extended my answer without up voting it  

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue. If you encounter a folder, push it to the queue. When all children in the current directory are done, then pull from the queue and dive in and repeat, more like a modified BFS.